# how to resolve error- property 'text' not found on 'object' of type UITableView in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, properties

I'm getting an error in the below code. `..L1name` , `L1email` , `L1code` are the property names for the array `nameData`, `nameEmail`, `nameCode`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleList1 *cell = (SimpleList1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.L1name.text = [nameData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.L1email.text = [nameEmail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.L1code.text = [nameCode objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is the error actually telling you about `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: did add label properly to customize in tablecell

Comment: i did add label property to customize tablecell

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a typo in your question title and the error is actually referencing `UITableViewCell`. This would be because `UITableViewCell` doesn't have your custom properties.

You need to ensure you have created an instance of your custom cell subclass, and that the variable is of the correct class type so the compiler knows what properties are available (casting if required):

```
MYCell *cell = (MYCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:...];
```

Comment: You need to show more code from the custom cell class and your cell creating / configuration then

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    
    SimpleList1 *cell = (SimpleList1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

Comment: What is in SimpleList1.h ? (and please check my edit for accuracy)